# Remove SNAPSHOT from all Maven sub-modules, but honor version

Tags: maven, versioning, multi-module

**Use Case**

I am working on a multi-module project and I am trying to drop `-SNAPSHOT` for all child modules that have different versions.

**Example**

For the purposes of this exercise we can assume there are two sub-modules. The articles [Maven Simple Project Archetype](https://maven.apache.org/archetypes/maven-archetype-simple/) and [Create an archetype from a multi-module project](https://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/examples/create-multi-module-project.html) can be referenced to follow along.

```
Parent - 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
ChildA - 1.2.3-SNAPSHOT
ChildB - 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

**Results**

When I run `mvn versions:set -D removeSnapshot -D processAllModules` I expect the versions to change as indicated below.

```
Parent - 1.0.0
ChildA - 1.2.3
ChildB - 1.0.0
```

But, it seems -SNAPSHOT is stripped from all versions except the children that have a different version from the parent.

```
Parent - 1.0.0
ChildA - 1.2.3-SNAPSHOT
ChildB - 1.0.0
```

Is there any way to run the `mvn versions:set` command to honor the version number, while stripping the `-SNAPSHOT` postfix?

---

**UPDATE #1**

Running `mvn versions:set -D removeSnapshot=true` yields the same results as running `mvn versions:set -D removeSnapshot -D processAllModules`.

```
Parent - 1.0.0
ChildA - 1.2.3-SNAPSHOT
ChildB - 1.0.0
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `-DremoveSnapshot=true`?

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes, please see section **UPDATE #1** in my answer.

Comment: A multi module build is typically used when all versions are identical...If you set different ... that's expected.

Comment: @khmarbaise That makes sense. Would you happen to know if this information can be found in Maven's official documentation? The closest thing I could find was [this section in the POM documentation](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#aggregation-or-multi-module), which the whole versions being the same concept of multi-module projects seems to be implied... right? Maybe I'm reading that incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Maven Enforcer documentation for multi-module projects](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/reactorModuleConvergence.html)...

> The best practice in Maven is that all childs inherit the version from
> their parent and don't define a new version which looks like this:

```
<parent>
  <groupId>...</groupId>
  <artifactId>...</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>module1</artifactId>
(..)
```

Additional use cases can be found in the linked article above.